# Admob iOS Ads without SDK

Tags: ios, admob

Does anybody have a suggestion to use Admob's iOS ads without using the iPhone SDK? What I ask is similar to "[API based integration](http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=Integration_Guidelines#API-Based_Integration)" feature of InMobi, i.e. You setup your web server and redirect requests to AdMob's iOS banner server and redirect the response to user. Please note that what I ask is quite different from AdMob's "mobile web" feature (which is soon to be discontinued)

The reason I don't want to use the SDK is to integrate ads without changing the installed apps on current users, because there is already a proper-sized UIWebView on my app which fetches some banners from my web site.

Comment: Why not just use InMobi? (disclaimer - I work for them!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, AdMob does not offer an API based integration of this nature.

Answer (score 0):

If you have integrated some Ad SDKs which support many mediations ,You can easily achieve this without changing the app you can add more mediation ads support from their web interface .There will be many features available like adding weights to the one mediation like admob or facebook which gives you more revenue .One of ad SDK which is free and having many mediation support is (http://www.vmax.com/)